# Microsoft SQL, ROW_NUMBER & OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I am having some problems with an outer apply, specifically that I cant reference ROW from within the OUTER APPLY.

Note if i place the where ROW criteria outside of the outer apply people without a 3 ,4 or 5th row for example aren't returned.

```
OUTER APPLY 
(
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER()
             OVER (ORDER BY L.DATECREATED) AS ROW,
             L.PERCENTAGE
             LABOURALLOCATION L
             ***WHERE ROW = 1***
) RECORDS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reference an aliased column in your where clause. You also can't put the `row_number()` function in your `where` or in a `having`. If you need to limit to `row = 1` within the `cross apply`, the only way to do it is to put the `row_number()` in a subquery or perhaps as a CTE. Note that `ROW` is a reserved word - I usually use `ROW_NUM`.

```
OUTER APPLY 
(
SELECT  ROW_NUM, PERCENTAGE
FROM    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER()
                     OVER (ORDER BY L.DATECREATED) AS ROW_NUM,
                     L.PERCENTAGE
                     FROM LABOURALLOCATION L
        )
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
) RECORDS
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Managed to get it working perfectly!